# Does Intellij Community edition allow setting VM options?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am unable to find the option of setting VM args to my Spring boot application in Intellij Community edition. Screenshot below:
[image]

AFAIK Intellij Community edition has an option to specify VM args. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screen where you are at: Click Modify Options. In the menu that appears, click Java -> Add VM Options. That is also accessible by a shortcut. Alt + V default on Windows.

[[image: IntelliJ Modify Options]

Once you checked Add VM Options a separate text box for VM options appear.